# how to set images into the viewpager from horizontalscrollview in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

i am trying to set images into the viewpager from horizontalscrollview.

i can not get the id of the horizontalscrollview to use in setcurrentItem method.

i have tried so many things but i could not.

Here is the MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int toplamSayfa = 5;
    private View btnNext, btnPrev;
    HorizontalScrollView hs;
    ImageView imageView = null;

    private Integer images[] = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e};

    ViewPager viewPager;

    LinearLayout myGallery;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, toplamSayfa);
        myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        hs = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.next);
        btnPrev = findViewById(R.id.prev);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        btnPrev.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(0));
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(onClickListener(1));

        addImagesToThegallery();
    }

    private void addImagesToThegallery() {

        final LinearLayout imageGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        for ( Integer image : images) {

            imageGallery.addView(getImageView(image));


    }

}

    private View getImageView(final Integer image) {
        imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             //the method where i am stuck 

                 viewPager.setCurrentItem();

            }
        });



        imageView.setImageResource(image);

        return imageView;
    }


    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i > 0) {

                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    }
                } else {

                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using viewpager and horizontalscrollview both?Use only ViewPager for paging the images.No need to use scrollview.

Comment: you are right, it is possible. but just trying different things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `addImagesToThegallery` method to keep the index of the image while adding the image to gallery from your `images` array :

```
private void addImagesToThegallery() {
  final LinearLayout imageGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

  int i = 0;
  for ( Integer image : images) {
    imageGallery.addView(getImageView(image,i));
    i += 1;
  }
}
```

and use the `index` here :

```
private View getImageView(final Integer image, int index) {
        imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             //use the index here

                 viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);

            }
        });



        imageView.setImageResource(image);

        return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. i would give a vote for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this , but ignore the if-else part:

```
package com.example.hotel_app_regularuser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PageTwo extends Activity {
ViewPager vpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_two);
        vpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
         PagerAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(PageTwo.this);
            vpager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page_two, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


 class customAdapter extends PagerAdapter
 {
Context context;
int imageId[]={
        R.drawable.chinese,
        R.drawable.euro,
        R.drawable.americanfood,
        R.drawable.continental

};
public customAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
    }


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,int position)
{
     Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.context.getAssets(), "fonts/Confetti.ttf");
    LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View viewitem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_two,container,false);
    ImageView im=(ImageView)viewitem.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    im.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
     TextView textView1 = (TextView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     if(position==0)
     {
     textView1.setText("Chinese");
     }
     if(position==1)
     {
     textView1.setText("European");
     }
     if(position==2)
     {
     textView1.setText("American");
     }
     if(position==3)
     {
     textView1.setText("Continental");
     }
     textView1.setTypeface(type);
     textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 70);
     textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
     ((ViewPager)container).addView(viewitem);



     return viewitem;
            }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageId.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0==((View)arg1);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

 }
```

To create a scroll view, try this xml file:

```
<!--  
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Check_Availability" 
     android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    android:id="@+id/main_table" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</TableLayout>      
   -->


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/main_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/header"/>                    
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note that the commented out section id for a page that used table layout. Hope this can help!